# UI-Router routing in the same view (View and Edit)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm not able to change the state from view page to edit page and vice versa in UI-Router.
Things I've tried:

Controller:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('showViewA', {
            views: {
                " ": {
                    template: "default.html",
                    controller:"DefaultController.ts"
                     },
                "viewB@showViewA": {
                    template: "viewPage.html",
                    controller:"DefaultController.ts"
                    }
            } 
        }) 
    .state('showViewA@EditshowViewA', {
            views: {
                " ": {
                    template: "defaultEdit.html",
                    controller:"DefaultEditController.ts"
                     }                 
            } 
        }) 
    .state('showViewA@ViewshowViewA', {
            views: {
                " ": {
                    template: "defaultShow.html",
                    controller:"DefaultShowController.ts"
                     }                 
            } 
        })
```

In `default.html` I'm loading only the view which I need to see when I first open the page.ie.,the edit page

```
<div ui-view="showViewA"></div>
```

which shows the edit page. On saving the edit page I need to replace the edit page with the view page which I have given a state `showViewA@ViewshowViewA`. But it's not redirecting. Can I know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/377c1kEGf9MjH1bASBej?p=preview)

Let's pretend that this is the *`default.html`* content:

```
<div >
  <h2>The default view (layout)</h2>

  <b>place holder for viewB</b>
  <hr />

  <div ui-view="viewB"></div>      
</div>
```

Then to make our states working with these links:

```
 <a ui-sref="showViewA">
 <a ui-sref="showViewA.EditshowViewA">
 <a ui-sref="showViewA.ViewshowViewA">
```

This would be the adjusted states definition *(changes are new lines - old are left with commented values)*.

Parent state with inner view, injected into `ui-view="viewB"` placeholder/anchor

```
    .state('showViewA', {
      url: '/',
      views: {
        //" ": {
        "": {
          //template: "default.html",
          templateUrl: "default.html",
          //controller:"DefaultController.ts"
          controller: "DefaultController"
        },
        "viewB@showViewA": {
          //template: "viewPage.html",
          templateUrl: "viewPage.html",
          //controller: "DefaultController.ts"
          controller: "DefaultController"
        }
      }
    })
```

Children injecting its view into the same ui-view="viewB"

```
  //.state('showViewA@EditshowViewA', {
  .state('showViewA.EditshowViewA', {
    views: {
      //" ": {
      "viewB": {
        //template: "defaultEdit.html",
        templateUrl: "defaultEdit.html",
        //controller:"DefaultEditController.ts"
        controller: "DefaultEditController"
      }
    }
  })
  //.state('showViewA@ViewshowViewA', {
  .state('showViewA.ViewshowViewA', {
    views: {
      //" ": {
      "viewB": {
        //template: "defaultShow.html",
        templateUrl: "defaultShow.html",
        //controller:"DefaultShowController.ts"
        controller: "DefaultShowController"
      }
    } 
  })
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/377c1kEGf9MjH1bASBej?p=preview)