# UI-router: how to show a state twice in a page with different parameters and sub-states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I have a parameterised state/route which is renders one "tab" in a multi-tab app. I was recently asked to put two of these tabs side-by-side.

UI-router provides the named views mechanism that would allow an existing state's controller to be shown multiple times at the same time. (See previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443770/ui-router-routing-in-the-same-view-view-and-edit).) However, I see no ways of passing different parameters to the controllers nor ways to maintain two separate sub-states.

Also, I previously used ui-router-extras' [deep state redirect](https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/dsr) to preserve the sub-states upon navigation, I am not sure how to get it work with the named views...

Edit:

Apparently, `<ui-view/>` that appear in named views will continue to render any child state's view. However, as there can only be one child view, the functionalities are still limited.

This is as far as I got going down the named views route:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3MbzPBrCHSk0vckpiITA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is not possible with ui-router right now, but probably possible with Angular 2's component router.

I have changed the states to be directives to work around this.